# Seed data in asp.net preview template web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

How should we seed data in asp.net preview web applications. I tried to use

> Enable-Migrations

command but it gave me the following error:

> Enable-Migrations : The term 'Enable-Migrations' is not recognized as
>   the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the  name, or if a path was included, verify
>   that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>   + Enable-Migrations
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-Migrations:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Have you installed Entity Framework?

Comment: If you've only just installed it, try restarting Visual Studio.  That, or try running Visual Studio as an administrator (although that should be unnecessary).

Comment: Do you have multiple projects?  If so, you need to make sure you're setting `Default project` in the package manager console to be the project which contains your context.

Comment: @JohnH I have only one project but as I have mentioned it's only ASP.NET Preview Template Web App.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84947/discussion-between-user2290194-and-john-h).